# How do I run ansible-galaxy installations using AWX?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-galaxy

So I've read over the other articles that are similar to this question and while they provided an accepted answer, I wasn't able to quite get there. I am running AWX on Fedora 35. I have installed it using the following guide.

https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-ansible-awx-on-centos/

After I finished this guy I also did

`yum install Ansible`

After I did what was said to do on the juniper website which is

`ansible-galaxy install collection juniper.device`

`sudo ansible-galaxy install Juniper.junos`

When I attempt to run my template I get the following.

[image: ansible-galaxy error]

The other article question/answer I read earlier stated (I also went to the Ansible site) that I need to create a requirements.yml file. I'm not sure where my issue is coming into play but I can't get it to work. Either I don't know where the requirements file is supposed to go. I put it in `/var/lib/awx/projects/_8__getconfigs/collections` and `/var/lib/awx/projects/_8__getconfigs/roles`

[image: /var/lib/awx/projects/_8__getconfigs/collections]

Inside of the files is very simple (and probably wrong).

Roles

```
---
roles:
  - name: Juniper.junos
```

Collections

```
---
collections:
  - name: juniper.devices
```

Lastly I was talking with someone earlier and they mentioned privileges which could make sense. There is no account for awx on my system. If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have the getConfig.yml file on github and pulled it from there. I created the inventory/host file on AWX itself as I couldn't figure out where the file is supposed to be stored. It looks like everything goes into a container, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi Dustin, did the answer help?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using Execution Environments in AWX

[image]

**1. Create a Dockerfile from awx-ee image containing the collections:**

```
    FROM quay.io/ansible/awx-ee:latest
    
    RUN ansible-galaxy collection install gluster.gluster \
     && ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
```

Build the Image: `docker build -t $ImageName .`
Log in to your Docker repository: `docker login -u $DockerHubUser`
Tag the image: `docker image tag $ImageName $DockerHubUser/$ImageName:latest`
Push the image to Hub: `docker image push $DockerHubUser/$ImageName:latest`

**2. Add Execution Environment to AWX:**
The image location, including the container registry, image name, and version tag
[image: EE]
**3. That's it:**
[image]
[image]
I've tested that already on a fresh AWX instance, where there is no collections installed.
You don't have to refer to the collection in a requirements.yml file
Whenever a new Galaxy Collection is needed, it should be added to the Dockerfile and pushed to Hub.
You can even install normal Linux packages in the docker image if needed.